# Removal of ";" from statements ;; in C

Tags: string

I need to remove ";" from statements in C which have ";;".
Eg:

```
main()
{
    int i;;
    int j,k;;
    int l;
    for(i=0;i<10;;)
    {}
}
```

should become:

```
main()
{
    int i;
    int j,k;
    int l;
    for(i=0;i<10;;)
    {}
}
```

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question.

Comment: Figure out how search and replace works in your editor.  This is really an editor question not a programming question.

Comment: Spence: What is the question?

Comment: Downvote it for being poorly worded, but closing it for being "not programming related"? Seriously?

Comment: "not a real question" ->

Comment: Of course it's a question (how do I do it?) and it's also programming-related! This is not solved by a mere search-and-replace.

Comment: @Sean: My point is that the guy has 11 rep. He's obviously new and could perhaps use a little help wording his very first question. Maybe we could be a little nicer to the newbs?

Comment: @Konrad: "I need to drink some coffee" does not imply "Where are the mugs?" / @Bill: fine, fine, I relent :P

Comment: @Sean: no, but "I need a mug" does.

Comment: @Konrad: cupboard next to the sink, bottom shelf :P

Answer (score 1):

UltraEdit could be a good choice..

Answer (score 1):

My first answer was wrong because I missed the ;; in the head of the for loop, which does serve a purpose.

The following perl script will replace all ;; followed by whitespace with a single ;.  It will do that for all C files (file extension .c) in the current directory and its subdirectories.

```
 perl -i -p -e 's/;;(\s*)$/;$1/g' `find | grep .c`
```

Thanks to Sean Bright for fixing my original mistake. (See the comments.)

I just want to point out that the extra ; at the end of line shouldn't really present a problem.  You could just leave them there, or you could just use your text editor to search and replace the ones that are extraneous.

Comment: The ;; would be replaced in the for loop, which isn't what he wants.

Comment: But is that what he wants? Its not clear.

Comment: @strager: Thanks, I missed that in the original format of the code.

Comment: @Bill: with a slight mod your example would work: perl -i -p -e 's/;;\s*$/;/g' `find | grep .c`

Comment: @Sean: Thanks, I modified it even further to preserve the whitespace.

Comment: @Bill: I considered that, but trailing whitespace is icky :P

Comment: @Sean: I think my solution will work. It just puts the same whitespace back in after replacing ;; with a single ;. I've only tried it with the OP's example, though.

Comment: @Bill: the * needs to go inside the parens, but otherwise it looks good (I don't feel comfortable editting other people's answers)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using **Find & replace** command. Any decent text editor has one (Notepad++, KWrite, not to mention Emacs).
Search for **;;** and replace it with **;**.

If you have plenty of code and `;` can happen inside char* values, use regexp :)

EDIT: Fine, you should search for: **;; *\n** and then replace it with **;\n**.

Comment: NOT to mention emacs? BLASPHEMER

Comment: :-D That was intentional :-D Always happy to amuse others :-D